# Библиотека okhttp, приложение вылетает в официальном примере

Tags: java, android, http, android-studio

Есть у **okhttp** библиотеки официальный пример

[Пример](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/square/okhttp/master/samples/guide/src/main/java/com/squareup/okhttp/guide/PostExample.java)

Когда дело доходит до этой строчки вылетает ошибка

```
Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
```

Если этот участок кода я запускаю в AsyncTask, то все работает

```
PostExample example = new PostExample();
    String json = example.bowlingJson("Jesse", "Jake");
    String response = example.post("http://www.roundsapp.com/post", json);
    System.out.println(response);
```

Что происходит? response крошит приложение потому что запускается в UI потоке? Но разве библиотека не должна сама запускать этот процесс в другом потоке по умолчанию? Если не должна то как это сделать, у библиотеки **okhttp** есть встроенные решения?

Comment: Всё есть. Читайте документацию, смотрите другие примеры. [Recipes](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Recipes)

Comment: пока не предъявите стактрейс, вам никто не поверит.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Дело в том, что вызов Call#execute() запускает запрос в текущем потоке. Скорее всего, вы вызываете этот класс из главного потока. В Android при вызове методов связанных с сетевой активностью из главного потока вызывается исключение [NetworkOnMainThreadException](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html).

Что бы избежать этого, кроме `AsyncTask`, можно использовать метод [enqueue](http://square.github.io/okhttp/javadoc/com/squareup/okhttp/Call.html#enqueue-com.squareup.okhttp.Callback-).

```
Call call = client.newCall(request);
call.enqueue(new Callback() {
  @Override public void onResponse(Response response) throws IOException {
    System.out.println(response.body.string());

  }
  @Override public void onFailure(Request request, IOException e) {
  }
});
```

Этот метод запускает запрос на одном из приватных потоков, так что исключения не возникает. Однако, нужно быть внимательным, т.к. колбеки вызываются на этих же приватных потоках, то нельзя напрямую обращаться к UI методам Android. Если нужно сделать что-то простое, то предпочтительнее использовать `AsyncTask`.

**UPDATE**:
Что-бы выполнить что-то на UI потоке, можно воспользоваться следущим универсальным приемом.

```
new Handler(Looper.getMainThread()).post(new Runnable() {
  @Override public void run() {
    // TODO:
  }
}
```

Но, как я уже говорил, желательнее использовать AsyncTask — этот механизм специально предназначен для упрощения таких вариантов использования.

Comment: Да, в onResponse я никак не могу обработать response, кроме как вывести в System.out.println. может подскажете как передать response  UI методам Android?

Comment: @Gennady, я обновил ответ.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Библиотека okHttp разочаровала, я думал, что в подобных библиотеках асинхронные запросы должны быть реализованы в самой библиотеке, даже официальные примеры не могли сделать чтоб работали без ошибок.

Comment: @Gennady, немогу согласится. okhttp очень даже хорошая библиотека, ее даже используют в ядре Android framework. Проблема в том что вы относитнть к этой библиотеке высокого уровня, в то воемя как okhttp библиотека низкого уровня - ее задача обеспечить соединение с сетью, и написана она для Java - она просто не знает (и не должна) о таком понятии как главный поток.

Comment: @Gennady я бы вам порекомендовал выбрать что-нибудь более высокоуровневое, например Retrofit, Volley или что то еще.