# Работа с HttpURLConnection в Android, полечение информации по GET

Tags: java, android, http, get, httpurlconnection

Нужно получить результат `GET` запроса в `Android` и вернуть значение из метода.
Решено! Всем спасибо за участие!

```
public void sayHello(View view)throws IOException {
        Thread httpThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                String mybla = sendGet();
            }
        });
        httpThread.start();
    }
private String sendGet(){
        try{
            String mystr = "http://www.pravda.com.ua";
            URL obj = new URL(mystr);
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
            con.setRequestMethod("GET");
            con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");
            con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8");
            InputStream response = con.getInputStream();
            Scanner s = new Scanner(response).useDelimiter("\\A");
            String result = s.hasNext() ? s.next() : "";
            return result;
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            return e.toString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Воспользуйтесь к-л либой для этого. Например `OkHttp`

Comment: А стандартной нельзя пользоваться?

Comment: Да, вроде, можно, но зачем, если есть спец либы, кои делают это лучше?..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Все делаете правильно. Для того, чтобы прочитать поток и получить из него `String`, можете воспользоваться, например, *библиотекой* **Apache commons `IOUtils`** ([офф. сайт](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/)). С её помощью:

```
String result = IOUtils.toString(inputStream);
```

Если предпочетаете способ без сторонних библиотек (что я приветствую, потому что это позволяет узнать что-то новое о языке, в котором вы новичек), то делайте например так:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(inputStream).useDelimiter("\\A");
String result = s.hasNext() ? s.next() : "";
```

**UPD**:

Заверните в

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        //вызовите ваш код для сетевого запроса
      }
    }).start();
```

Когда ваш запрос вернул результат внутри вашего `Thread`, чтобы поменять элемент интерфейса вам понадобится сделать это из UI-потока. Для этого используйте `Context.runOnUiThread();`.

Comment: Работа без сторонних библиотек это то то нужно, но при выполнении кода выдает ошибку android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

Comment: Как кто-то уже говорил, андроид не разрешает выполнять сетевые запросы в главном потоке. Используйте `AsyncTask`, или `Thread`.

Comment: Мастер=) научи))
Можно более детально рассказать как использовать @ ?

Comment: @Mikhail Отредактировал вопрос

Comment: ок, а как тогда вывести результат запроса на TextView?

Comment: Хочу в потоке запустить метод, но выдает ошибку.
Ругается вот на этот метод -> String mybla = sendGet();
Если в потоке просто запустить, то сразу материться на URL obj = new URL(mystr);

Comment: Обновил ответ. А вообще, ответ на все эти вопросы уже был дан много раз на английском StackOverflow и вообще уже расписан и разжеван по всему интернету. Все, что вам нужно - Google.

Answer (score 0):

Код с использованием либы [OkHttp](https://github.com/square/okhttp)

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().build();

String url = ...;

Request.Builder request = new Request.Builder();
request.url(url);
request.get();

Response response = client.newCall(request.build()).execute();

String response = response.body().string();
System.out.println(response );
```

Надо помнить, что на андроид запросы в сеть можно с API14 делать только вне UI потока. Например через AsynkTask, Thread etc

Comment: Если при запросе не требуется взаимодействие с UI-потоком, то OkHTTP имеет свои [встроенные инструменты](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/417920/177345) для асинхронных запросов. Volley, как мне помниться, изначально все запросы шлет в асинхронном режиме.

Comment: Этот код будет выполнен в том потоке, откуда его вызывают, насколько я вижу.

Comment: @pavlofff, хм, про `enqueue` не знал, спасибо)